# How to add a picture into the header in the first page?

Tags: header-footer

how can I add a picture into the header in the first page of my article? Thank you very much in advance.

My sample code can only create a file with the picture showing up on the second page.

```
\documentclass[12pt,a4paper]{article}
\usepackage{grffile,graphicx,hyperref,graphbox} \usepackage{fancyhdr}
\usepackage[sort]{natbib} \usepackage[svgnames]{xcolor}
\pagestyle{fancy} \renewcommand{\headrulewidth}{0pt} 

\usepackage[top=1in,headsep=4pt,headheight=26pt,bottom=1.in,left=1in,right=1in]{geometry}
\graphicspath{{C:/Users/header/}}
\renewcommand{\refname}{References} 
\begin{document}
\lhead{\includegraphics[width=1cm]{photo}}

{\centering \title{Stat} \author{Yan} 
\maketitle} 

I would like to \clearpage

123456

\bibliographystyle{chicago}
\bibliography{C:/Users//Downloads/ref/rref}
\end{document}
```

[image][image]

Comment: Add `\thispagestyle{fancy}` just after `\maketitle`.  The reason is that `\maketitle`modifies the page style.

Comment: Thanks. But on the last page, the picture is paired with "reference". Why? Thank you a lot.

Comment: Do you want the picture *only* in the first page?

Comment: Right. But I want to solve the problem of pairing photo with reference at first.

Comment: @Carl: the problem of paring a photo with reference = a second question. Please create a new question for that.

Answer (score 2):

I took the liberty of cleaning your code a bit

```
\documentclass[12pt,a4paper]{article}

\usepackage{grffile,graphicx,hyperref,graphbox}
\usepackage{fancyhdr}
\usepackage[sort]{natbib}
\usepackage[svgnames]{xcolor}
\usepackage[top=1in,headsep=4pt,headheight=26pt,bottom=1.in,left=1in,right=1in]{geometry}
\usepackage{lipsum}

%% HEADER %%
\pagestyle{fancy}
\renewcommand{\headrulewidth}{0pt}
\renewcommand{\bibsection}{}

\fancypagestyle{firststyle}
{
   \fancyhf{}
   \lhead{\includegraphics[width = 2cm]{example-image-a}}
}

% AUTHOR INFO
\title{Stat}
\author{Yan}


%% DOCUMENT
\begin{document}
\maketitle
\thispagestyle{firststyle}


\section{One section}
\lipsum[1-2]\clearpage

\section{Other section}
\lipsum[3-5]\cite{White1983}

\bibliographystyle{plain}
\section*{References}
\bibliography{refs}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Thank you a lot. Could you tell me what does the "\lipsum[1-2]" and "\lipsum[3-5]" mean or function here? It returned me with the error that "Package kantlipsum Error: Package expl3 too old. }" after I ran your code. Thanks.

Comment: @Carl Just some dummy text

Comment: And if you add up the command, "\bibliography{C:/Users/ref/rref}, which a bib.tex file, my previous problem wasn't solved. Thank you.

Comment: @Carl Do you want `References` to appear on the header? or you don't? It appears there because the header is configured to include the current section title.

Comment: I don't. Thank you for your instructions.

Comment: But, in that way, no words of "references" will show up on the last page.

Comment: @Carl How about now?

Comment: I don't see other problems if citing papers in the body of the document. Thanks.